# Model array values are not being submitted by $http service

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, angularjs-scope

I defined an array in controller to create a array model. i.e. `$scope.campaignPublish[]` and I am using in my view template like

```
<textarea rows="" cols="" name="description" ng-model="campaignPublish['description']"> </textarea>

<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="campaignPublish['title']">
```

When I submit the form I'm getting all of the form values in this array i.e. `$scope.campaignPublish[]` but when I'm using `$http.post`, the data is not being submitted to server. My ajax call is

```
console.log($scope.campaignPublish); // Getting all form data here 

$http.post('url', {'id': campaignId, 'data': $scope.campaignPublish}).then(function (response) {
   //$http.post is not submitting the form data on server
});
```

I read some articles and got to know that it is happening because of `http headers`. I've already tried each and every solution posted on `SO` but no one exactly worked. Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        data: $scope.campaignPublish
    }).success(function (reply) {
        console.log('sucess');
    }).error(function (reply) {
        console.log('error');
    });
```

Comment: $scope.campaignPublish = {} this is a json not array. so dont declare it as array.